# Unexpected response code for operation : 99 in Azure table storage error

Tags: azure-storage

When I deployed the project in staging environment the values are stored correctly in azure table storage after I swapped the deployment production environment in azure this issue will be rising. I don't know what is the exact problem anyone help me.
     Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that the 100th operation in a batch transaction (aka [Group Entity Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894038.aspx)) failed and therefore the entire batch transaction failed. If you enable [Storage Analytics logging](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/#configurelogging), each individual operation will have a separate log entry and therefore you can easily identify the issue.